# How can you connect a 4 ohm 3 watt speaker to arduino mega?

Tags: arduino, circuit

I am currently using an Arduino Mega 2560 and before I tried hooking it up with a big speaker to play sounds and I want to connect the arduino to a smaller one and I have a spare 4 ohm 3 watt speaker that I don't use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Can you hook it up? Well technically you also *could* stick a fork into a power socket. Either of which is ill advised.

*No, you can't drive a 4 ohm speaker with an Arduino directly.*

An Arduino can deliver 20mA of current top; or rather, that's the maximum amount of current the output drivers of the used microcontroller are rated for. At 4V of voltage a 4 ohms load will draw a current of 1A = 1000mA so 50 times the current capability of the Arduino.

Furthermore, since the output drivers of the micro are not designed to drive such low impedance loads, due to the bad impedance mismatch, it will not be able to deliver any substancial amount of power in the first place. All it will see is essentially a short circuit, that will blow that poor circuit.

Comment: So directly I can't, but is there something that I could do to connect it to my Arduino, like add some components?

Comment: Any device accepting a Line Out  signal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level Reduced by a pot to 3:5 or less, and a capacitor to eliminate the DC offset